# ReadFile of Windows api is not reading all the data send from USB device

Tags: c#, wpf, readfile

I m trying to read the data that is send from a USB device connected with laptop.
device send data as mention below:

```
 52-30-30-45-46-30-34-31

 41-33-35-32-31-43-41-30

 32-0D
```

I am able to get first and second payload but the thread stop in third time did not get any thing.

I m using asynchronous process to read the data. Below I have mention some code snap for the reference. Process is continuous read process

```
ReadFinished = NativeMethods.CreateEvent(IntPtr.Zero, true, false, "killread");

// Create event used to signal a read has completed
IntPtr eventObject = NativeMethods.CreateEvent(IntPtr.Zero, false, false, "");

// Clear out any waiting input data 
NativeMethods.HidD_FlushQueue(handle);

// Allocate memory for the input buffer and overlapped structure. 
IntPtr nonManagedBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(InputReportLength);
IntPtr nonManagedOverlapped = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(hidOverlapped));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(hidOverlapped, nonManagedOverlapped, false);
UInt32 numberOfBytesRead = 0;

Boolean success = NativeMethods.ReadFile(handle, nonManagedBuffer, (UInt32)InputReportLength, ref numberOfBytesRead, nonManagedOverlapped);
// Timeout set to infinite - will not return until signalled
Int32 result = NativeMethods.WaitForMultipleObjects(2, events, false, 0xFFFFFFFF);

//  If read completed successfully, get the data
NativeMethods.GetOverlappedResult(handle, nonManagedOverlapped, ref numberOfBytesRead, true);
```

above all these method are used in process.
I tried to put all the detail. Please let me know if require any other details.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the sample above represent 3 different files? Would the behavior change if the data is not on USB? This is a good reference for how to handle multiple files asynch way:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/asynchronous-file-i-o

Comment: Above sample is from a single file. All the actions perform in a single file HIDAccessory.

Comment: In the file there is a continuous read function when we start the tool this function called and create the events and do a NativeMethods.ReadFile operation.
And again any input come it get data from NativeMethods.GetOverlappedResult and do a readfile operation to read the next data bytes. But it only read two time and third time it did not get any data I tried missing data multiple time but always return false. I am not gettin why third time ReadFile operation did not get any data.

Comment: I am not familiar with your scenario but reading the same file asynch is not a good idea in most cases I can think of. It makes sense to process multiple files asynch but not a single file.